# -mäßig vs. -artig

Tags: translation, suffix

In manchen Fällen wird beides als "-like" übersetzt. Woher weiß man, welche der beiden Endungen benutzt werden soll? Insbesondere bezüglich Gegenständen und so. Also, sagt man eher pulvermäßig oder pulver*artig*, zystenmäßig oder zysten*artig*?

Comment: Ich bin nur mäßig artig. ;-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The suffix *-mäßig* refers to something being done in a certain way, very much like an adverb, whereas *-artig* refers to something simply being that way.

> gleichmäßig = evenly, equally
>   
>  gleichartig = similar, uniform